# Which one is right - "Между двух людей" or "Между двумя людьми"

Tags: грамматика, лексикон, числительные, словоупотребление

I wonder which version is grammatically correct -

> Между двух людей

or

> Между двумя людьми

Some website said that they are both correct, is it truly so?

P.S If you need some context, here you go

> Стать между двух людей

or

> Стать между двумя людьми

Comment: In modern Russian, the case *между + instrumental* is "more" grammatically correct. *Между + genitive* can be used, but it's quite obsolete. It often appears in old texts.

Comment: Между двумями людями!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was already in 1937 that Dmitry Ushakov in his famous four-volume dictionary wrote that using *между* with the Genitive case was **obsolete**. *Между двух людей* is obsolete, because *двух людей* is Genitive. Look, it's wrong to use *между* with Genitive, it's impossible to say **между меня и тебя*, **авиаперелёт между двух стран*, **отношения между матери и сына* — such phrases sound too weird, only the Instrumental case should be used after *между*: ***между двумя людьми***, *между мной и тобой*, *авиаперелёт между двумя странами*, *отношения между матерью и сыном.*

*Между* in the online version of Ushakov's dictionary [can be found here](http://ushakovdictionary.ru/word.php?wordid=29260). The beginning of the article:

> **МÉЖДУ**, предлог с твор. п. (с двумя твор. падежами ед. или мн. ч.; если же с одним твор. п., то со словом "собой" или с твор. п. мн. ч.; **с одним или двумя род. падежами мн. ч. - устар**., а **с двумя род. падежами ед. ч. теперь совсем не употр.**). 1. Служит для обозначения положения предмета или проявления действия в промежутке, посредине чего-н. В котловине между горами протекал ручей. между окном и дверью стоял шкаф. между Ленинградом и Москвой. между небом и землей. Всюду между деревьев... мелькали белые, синие, красные рубахи. Тургенев. между двух огней (см. огонь). между ясминов и лилей. Карамзин. всем между собой. между нами существует такой обычай. Разделить что-н. между собой.

Answer (score 1):

Technically speaking both are correct. On the other hand, you wouldn't normally use *"между двух людей"*, especially in spoken language, because here you're adding an unnecessary syllable. Instead you can say the same as *"Стать меж двух людей"*. It is grammatically correct, can be used in both written and spoken language and sounds cleaner.

At the same time, the aforementioned version is slightly old-school and in modern spoken language most people would choose *"Между двумя людьми"* instead.

Answer (score -1):

Между двух людей is right in your context, but между двумя людьми can be used in context of choosing (like choosing the game to play: "Выбрать между двумя играми"/"To choose between two games").

It happens because in two different cases these words are having different declensions: "между двух людей" are answering to the question "кого?" and "между двумя людьми" are answering to "кем?".

Comment: Most probably, some people consider _между двух людей_ possible or even correct because this phrase gets contaminated with _среди людей_,  _среди_ with Genitive being absolutely correct.

Comment: Между двумя людьми  http://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&mydocsize=&mode=main&sort=i_grtagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&text=lexform&req=%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83+%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%BC%D1%8F+%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B4%D1%8C%D0%BC%D0%B8

Comment: Между двух людей http://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&mydocsize=&mode=main&sort=i_grtagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&text=lexform&req=%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83+%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%85++%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B9

Comment: Google Books Ngram Viewer [shows](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Между+двух+людей%2Cмежду+двумя+людьми&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=25&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cмежду%20двумя%20людьми%3B%2Cc0) the same result as ruscorpora.ru: no search results found for _между двух людей_.